# HTML can't load CSS when i clicked in directly but when I go live with VSCode it loads fine

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

My CSS file somehow not loaded when i clicked my html file directly in my folder. But somehow with vscode when go live after compiling the scss to css it works fine.

do you guys have any idea why?
I place my css file in dist folder when using the Live Sass Compiler.
I tried open the html directly from folder using all the browser i have but the css not loaded.

```css
body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/test.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1> TEST </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what kind of browser do you have?

Comment: can u provide the folder structure in order to understand more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use absolute path, you should use relative path

instead of `/dist/test.css`try `dist/test.css`

If you want to read more, here is an article about absolute/relative path:
https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

The preview work on vscode because vscode probably use a localserver to run your html file. something like localhost:3000/index.html. So in this case your html file is at the root of the domain, that's why the absolute path will be the same as the relative path

Comment: Thanks it works. 
but 1 more problem. I use image with css background attribute with url lead to an image folder, the other style is loaded but the image not showed up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/test.css"/>`

Comment: It won't change his problem. Moreover, the attribute type is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `./dist/test.css`, this will also works fine